# How to recover overwritten native methods?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on a project and noticed that one of the core developers overwrote `alert()` method in his JS.

Is it possible to recover it without asking/changing his code?

He did something like..

```
function alert() {
   // his code
}
```

Comment: How did he overwrite it?

Comment: function alert() { // his own code here }

Comment: Are you using revision control? I guess I don't understand the question if not.  Are you asking how you can un-save a file?

Comment: And your code has to come after that code?

Comment: @MikeBrant // yes, and I can simply remove his code. I just don't want to touch a core code.

Comment: Whapping the developer with a newspaper would be the best option. The correct solution that won't break current code that depends on the redefinition would be saving the old `alert()` **before** clobbering it under a different name (like `_alert()`) then using that.

Comment: @minitech // yes, it should go after his code.

Comment: That said, why use the native alert() in the first place? `console.log` or a DHTML dialog is almost always nicer.

Comment: @millimoose // I don't want any fancy DHTMl dialog. I just want to use the native one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can make an intermediate `<iframe>`.](http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/oILEr)

```
var f = document.createElement("iframe");
f.width = 0;
f.height = 0;
f.src = "about:blank";
f.onload = function() {
    f.contentWindow.alert("Hi!");
    document.body.removeChild(f);
};
document.body.appendChild(f);
```

Don’t make an intermediate `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can inject code before the code that's causing this problem, you can "fix" it:

E.g.

```
window._alert = window.alert;
// bad code ..
window.alert = function() {};
// restore correct function
window.alert = window._alert;
```

Of course, that means that the other code might now function incorrectly or cause unwanted alert boxes.

It also depends on how exactly the other code is overwriting `alert`. If it's just sloppy code where a function called `alert` is being hoisted to the global scope by mistake, you potentially fix it by wrapping the whole codeblock in an anonymous function:

```
(function() {
    // scope to this block
    var alert;

    // bad code here
    alert = function() {};
})();
// alert doesn't pollute global scope:
alert("HI");
```

Comment: Of course you could also use `_alert()` explicitly instead of restoring it.

Comment: Actually, wrapping `alert = function() {};` in anonymous function will still put it in the global scope.

Comment: Yes, missed the `var` to fix the scope. fixed.