# Why doesn't "console.log()" work on this website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log, devtools

I can open the Chrome DevTools console for this URL: https://www.google.com/ and enter the following command to print "Hello world!" to the console:

`console.log("Hello world!")`

However, when I attempt to use the same command for this URL: https://svc.mt.gov/dor/property/prc my message isn't printed in the console. Why is that?

Is there any way to force the console to work for this MT website?

I've tried using python/selenium to open the page and execute_script() to issue the command, but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Not a duplicate IMO, but see also [How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools), as it is asking something closely related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do

```
console.dir(console.log)
```

and click on the `[[FunctionLocation]]`, you'll see the following in the site's source code:

```
"Debug" != e && (window.console.log = function() {}
    )
```

Seems like a cheap (but lazy?) way to suppress logging on production.

One way to fix it, kinda, would be to use [one of the many other console commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console). (`console.dir`, or `console.error`, if you want)

If you really want the original `console.log` to work again, the only way to do that would be to run code *before* the page code runs, so that you can save a reference to the function. For example, with a userscript:

```
// <metadata block...>
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

const origConsoleLog = console.log;
// set original window.console.log back to its original
// after the page loads
setTimeout(() => {
  window.console.log = origConsoleLog;
}, 2000);

// there are more elegant but more complicated approaches too
```

Comment: Please do not say "Thank you" as a comment. If an answer helped you, instead, please [accept that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

CertainPerformance already explained how this is possible and what the reason for suppressing the log seems to be. I'm going to show here another method to get back `console.log` after the original has been lost.

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('IFRAME')).onload = function () {
    this.contentWindow.console.log('Hello, World!');
    this.remove();
};
```

This basically uses an old method of [restoring global objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19017427/1083663) from a temporary iframe.

Comment: You could even do `console.log = this.contentWindow.console.log`, though in this case you'd need to not `.remove()` the iframe in Firefox.